# how do i handle the error for firebase cloud function api oncall?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

how do i handle the error for firebase admin api oncall? should I throw an error or return the response? and also am I doing the success return response correctly?

```
exports.registerVendor = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const email = data.email;
    const displayName = data.firstName + data.lastName;

    // Checking attribute.
    if (!(typeof email === 'string') || email.length === 0 || 
        !(typeof displayName === 'string') || displayName.length === 0) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
    }

    // const uid = context.auth?.uid;

    // Checking that the user is authenticated.
    if (!context.auth) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 
            'The function must be called ' + 'while authenticated.');
    }

    try {
        const createResponse = await admin.auth().createUser({
            email: email,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: '123123',
            displayName: displayName,
            disabled: false
          })

        console.log(createResponse);

        return {
            data: {
                uid: createResponse.uid
            },
            status: 200,
            code: "Success"
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err as Error);
        // throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.code, err.message);
        return {
            error: err,
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If this code is in a Callable Cloud Function, please edit your question to include that entire function, and likely how you call it.

Comment: noted, changed.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation on [handling errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) contains this example:

> ```
> // Checking attribute.
> if (!(typeof text === 'string') || text.length === 0) {
>   // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
>   throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
>       'one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
> }
> // Checking that the user is authenticated.
> if (!context.auth) {
>   // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
>   throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
>       'while authenticated.');
> }
> ```

So this is the recommended way to get an error condition from the server to the caller, and you'd then [handle them on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client). But you can also return your own error code as you are doing now.

Comment: As said, the documentation recommends another way. But if what you have works for you, it looks fine to me.